# Intersection of a curve on an exceptional divisor with the exceptional divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $q: W \to X$ be a proper birational morphism of quasi-projective varieties. Let $E$ be an effective, $q$-exceptional divisor. Suppose $C \subseteq E$ is a curve, then is it true that the intersection $C \cdot E < 0$?

I had a very vague idea to "prove" such "result" (and I think this is somehow the standard way) : cut $X$ by hypersufaces and prove the result for surfaces using Hodge index theorem. However, I am not very confident with how to do the induction step...neither do I know the validity of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm sorry, this should be a comment, but I cannot comment yet). 
I am not sure your claim is true.

Take a quartic surface $X \subset \mathbb P^3$ with a singularity $p$ of type $A_3$ and let $W$ be a minimal resolution. $W$ is a K3 surface and the fibre over $p$ is a divisor $E$ with three rational irreducible components $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$, such that $C_i \cdot C_{i+1}=1$ for $i=1,2$ and $C_i^2 = -2$.

If you take $C = C_2$ then $C \cdot E = 1 -2 +1 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Then is it possible to claim $E \cdot C \leq 0$?

Comment: Mm, if you take a $D_4$ singularity then you get four rational curves $C_i$, $i=0,1,2,3$, arranged with dual graph $D_4$. If you take $E = C_0 + \cdots + C_3$ and $C$ the only component that intersects all other three, then $C \cdot E = -2 +1+1+1 = 1$.
(I haven't found an example with $E = q^*(p)$, with $p$ a point in $X$, though.)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your definition of "$q$-exceptional divisor": I just assumed it is a divisor which gets contracted by $q$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much! I define $q$-exceptional the same way as you did. I will try to think hard about your examples.

Comment: This post on MO may also be of help: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69554/curves-negative-for-an-exceptional-divisor. (Note that the statement in the question is false!)

Comment: Thank you, this post is very helpful!!